# jQuery - Display div if it matches only two certain words

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, contains

If I wanted to display the install_option div *only* if the words "Apple iPad" are present in the title?

Could also do with matching if a product is called ipad (lowercase) or Ipad

```
<h1 id="pbtitle">Apple iPad 3</h1>


<div class="install_option" style="display:none;">              
    <div style="width:35%; box-sizing:border-box; float:left;">
        <h3 style="font-weight:bold;">Would you like to view accessories?</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="apple_install_option" style="padding-top:20px;">
        <a href="https://www.apple.com" target="_blank">
                <img alt="Apple.com" src="http://cdn.cultofmac.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/lightningconnector.jpg" style="margin-right:20px; max-width:200px; height: auto;">
        </a>
    </div>

</div>


$(".install_option").each(function() {
  var brand = $("h1#pbtitle").text().toLowerCase();
  if (brand != "Lenovo") {
    $('.install_option').css('display', 'block');
  }
});
```

**https://jsfiddle.net/ote8w56v/**

Comment: The jsfiddle shown above doesn't work. This one does: https://jsfiddle.net/54eg8cn6/

Comment: You can use `.indexOf`, like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ote8w56v/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [indexOf](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) to see if a string contains some words, if it does it will return the index, if not it returns `-1` so just check that it doesn't return `-1`, like so:

```js
$(".install_option").each(function() {
  var brand = $("h1#pbtitle").text().toLowerCase();
  if (brand.indexOf("ipad") != -1) {
    $('.install_option').css('display', 'block');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Product names include Apple iPad, Acer Iconia, Lenovo Thinkpad -->

<h1 id="pbtitle">Apple Ipad 3</h1>


<div class="install_option" style="display:none;">              
    <div style="width:35%; box-sizing:border-box; float:left;">
     <h3 style="font-weight:bold;">Would you like to view accessories?</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="apple_install_option" style="padding-top:20px;">
  <a href="https://www.apple.com" target="_blank">
    <img alt="Apple.com" src="http://cdn.cultofmac.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/lightningconnector.jpg" style="margin-right:20px; max-width:200px; height: auto;">
  </a>
 </div>

</div>
```

Comment: How could it be triggered on a range of keywords such as Lenovo, Microsoft, Acer etc?

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
$(".install_option").each(function () {
    var thisElement=$(this);
    var brand = thisElement.find("h1").text().toLowerCase();
    if (/ipad/.test( brand )) {
        thisElement.css('display', 'block');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `indexOf` You can do this. For more Details Refer [**Link**](https://api.jquery.com/index/)

```js
$(".install_option").each(function() {
  var brand = $("h1#pbtitle").text().toLowerCase();
  if (brand.indexOf("ipad") != -1) {
    $('.install_option').css('display', 'block');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Product names include Apple iPad, Acer Iconia, Lenovo Thinkpad -->

<h1 id="pbtitle">Apple Ipad 3</h1>


<div class="install_option" style="display:none;">              
    <div style="width:35%; box-sizing:border-box; float:left;">
     <h3 style="font-weight:bold;">Would you like to view accessories?</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="apple_install_option" style="padding-top:20px;">
  <a href="https://www.apple.com" target="_blank">
    <img alt="Apple.com" src="http://cdn.cultofmac.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/lightningconnector.jpg" style="margin-right:20px; max-width:200px; height: auto;">
  </a>
 </div>

</div>
```

Comment: How could it be triggered on a range of keywords such as Lenovo, Microsoft, Acer etc?